# Cada vez que ejecuto el paquete de tarea flujo de datos se duplican los datos SSIS

Tags: ssis

Quiero insertar datos de una tabla a otra mediante el paquete de SSIS " tarea flujo de datos" , pero existen datos en la tabla destino que ya existen en la tabla origen y los duplica cuantas veces ejecute el paquete, ¿alguna forma de evitar la duplicación de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade un componente *Lookup (Búsqueda)* para comprobar si los datos existen en destino.

1. Configura el componente para redirigir las filas que no hagan match

[image: Lookup Component]

2. En la pestaña de Connection, asigna la conexión donde se encuentra tu tabla destino y selecciona la tabla destino.
3. En Columns une las columnas primarias

[image: Match columns]

4. Une el componente Lookup con el OleDbDestination y cuando te pida seleccionar el Output, elige No Match

[image: No Match Output]

**Resultado:** 
De esta forma, cuando ejecutes el paquete, la primera vez se moverán todas las filas entre origen y destino

[image: Flujo de datos]

Pero en las siguientes ejecuciones, solo se moverán aquellos datos que no se encuentren en tu tabla destino

[image: Flujo de datos 2]

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Inserta la información en una tabla temporal y luego cruza para borrar.

```
DELETE a
FROM #TMP_DATOS b INNNER JOIN dbo.TABLA_DESTINO ON a.llave = b.llave
```

Luego si realiza la tarea de Inserción

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crear un job para ese paquete, en el que previamente en un paso, limpie la tabla con un `truncate` y en el siguiente paso ejecute el paquete de SSIS y listo.